# VeraCrypt MountVolume:9170 Error

Tags: veracrypt

Yesterday I got this error when I wanted to open the disk that I protected with Veracrypt. I am absolutely sure that the password I use is correct because I use the same password everywhere. I would appreciate if you could help me how to solve this problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ateO.png

Comment: Get a password manager like Bitwarden and stop using the same password everywhere.

Comment: Ok thanks but that's not my problem.

Comment: It is one of your problems. Do you have backups of your Veracrypt volume?

Comment: No, what I mean is that my password is definitely not wrong. I don't have a Veracrypt backup unfortunately.

Comment: Could be the volume is damaged, or, if someone else has access, they changed the password: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/103638/veracrypt-is-it-possible-to-change-the-password-after-an-encrypted-container-ha

Comment: if its a volume file rather than a device, you might run a filesystem integrity check on the underlying filesystem storing the volume. if there are bad blocks/sectors intersecting the files storage, it may be able to reallocate them.

Comment: No the Disk is not encrypted, I created a Veracrypt partition inside the Disk and encrypted it. Is it possible to recover this file?

Comment: right, but  you cannot scan the filesystem of an encrypted partition without being able to at least authenticating successfully. you did select a device rather than a volume file in veracrypt, right? can't see it under the error message popup.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had the same problem..... and got it ;)

I was pretty sure my password was correct but I got an error wrong Password and mount error 9170.

What helped me was:
-Add Veracrypt.exe into trusted programms in Windows 10 or newer otherwise
the programm is not able to decrypt files or hard Disks it won't work
properly!!

Update and Safety -> Windows Security -> Ransomware Protection -> Allow
Acces through App and then choose last blocked app or Veracrypt.exe !!!!

-Volume operation recover Volume head in Veracrypt -> Volume Operation

Kind regards
Christian Wolf

Answer (score 0):

I am having preety much the same problem, the problem is laptop got stuck after a failed update of Intel Firmware and it gets a black screen at turning it on.

I tried to decrypt the hard drive on another computer but I am getting the same error on normal decrypt.
On Volume - Recover Volume Head I am getting another error : 11148

On the Soundforge forum nobody responds. Maybe somebody has any solution because I just got stuck with my work.

Thanks

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1147276)